# SharedPreferences throws a FATAL Exception when reading SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am accessing SharedPreferences to get a value that is not inserted yet. I use this code:

```
public long getWifiWorldTimeStamp(){
    long timestamp = defaultPreferences.getLong(TIMESTAMP_TILES_WORLD, 0);
    return timestamp;
}
```

I have never write on SharedPreferences with this key so, function must return a 0 (in order of default value). The problem is that it is throwing this:

```
12-01 18:00:04.281 6837-7661/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-574
 Process: com.aaaa.bbbb.debug, PID: 6837
 java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:145)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:125)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:103)
     at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.getHttpClient(HttpRequest.java:214)
     at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:141)
     at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
     at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
     at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
     at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
```

Edit:

This is where I call the function:

```
@Override
public void execute(final CallbackGetAll callback) {
    long savedTimeStamp = preferences.getWifiWorldTimeStamp();
    if (preferences.getWifiWorldTimeStamp() == 0 || ((System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000) > savedTimeStamp) {
        getFromServer(callback);
    } else {
        readWifiWorldFromFile(callback);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I think the problem come from other part. Debuging the app, seems that it throws a **java.lang.ClassCastException** when triying to read from the SharedProperties. Particullary a **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long**.

I don't understand why, I store a long value in the SharedPreferences but when I read it it crashes. I hae tried int and String values too with the same result.

This is the code I use to write, read, and where are the used.

Storing values:

```
public void saveWifiWorldTimeStamp(String wifiWorldTimeStamp){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = defaultPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TIMESTAMP_TILES_WORLD, wifiWorldTimeStamp);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Reading values

```
public String getWifiWorldTimeStamp(){
    String timestamp = defaultPreferences.getString(TIMESTAMP_TILES_WORLD, "0");
    return timestamp;
}
```

Where I need to get the values stored

```
@Override
public void execute(final CallbackGetAll callback) {
    int savedTimeStamp = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getWifiWorldTimeStamp());
    if (savedTimeStamp == 0 || Integer.parseInt(getCurrentTimestamp()) > savedTimeStamp) {
        getFromServer(callback);
    } else {
        readWifiWorldFromFile(callback);
    }
}
```

Where I write in SharedPreferences:

```
@Override
public void onSuccessWebService(final JSONArray response, String etag) {
    final List<WiFiGlobe> wifiGlobeList = ConverterUtils.convertJSONArrayInWifiGlobeList(response);

            saveWifiWorldToFile(response);

    preferences.saveWifiWorldTimeStamp(getTimestampToSave());
    preferences.saveEtagTilesWorld(etag);

    LogsInDebugMode.log(TAG, "getFromServer FINISH");
    callback.onSuccess(wifiGlobeList);
}
```

This is how I call execute()

```
private void getWifiSpotsFromWorld(Location mCurrentLocation, float zoomLevel) {
    WiFiTile wifiTile = new WiFiTile();
    wifiTile.setZoomLevel((int) zoomLevel);
    wifiTile.calculateTile(mCurrentLocation);

    getWifiSpotsFromWorldInteractor.execute(wifiTile, new GetWifiSpotsFromWorldInteractorImpl.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<WiFiGlobe> wiFiGlobeList) {
            CopyOnWriteArrayList<WiFiGlobe> wifisCopyList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<WiFiGlobe>(wiFiGlobeList);
            //TODO: Modificar la View para el método de pintado de globos
            SpotsMapPresenterImpl.wifiWorldSpotsList = wifisCopyList;
            view.showWifiWorldspots(wifisCopyList);
            view.hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String errorText) {
            ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new MyEventException("Getting venues failed: " + errorText));
            view.showPopUpMessage(errorText);
            view.hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingToRefresh() {
            LogsInDebugMode.error(TAG, "No need to update WifiWorld On Map");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `com.aaaa.bbbb.debug` is your app package name?

Comment: Is this the whole stack trace?

Comment: At first shot it looks like the exception is not die to the pretences method above. How you say that's the reason. .add more info and required code.

Comment: com.aaa.bbbb.debug is not the real app package name. I have changed it due to confidentiality.

Comment: Seems like you are accessing SharedPreferences in a background thred

Comment: exception is rising due to thread, kindly share complete code

Comment: There error looks to be thrown at `HttpRequest.getHttpClient`, which I assume is from `getFromServer`

Comment: is execute function getting called in background thread?

Comment: how you initialize `defaultPreferences`? can you put code of `defaultPreferences` initialization? some thing like `myContext.getSharedPreferences("MyProps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: I have updated with the method that call execute().